# Remove FILL from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How would I remove specific, yet slightly random text from a string in JavaScript?

EG:

a string `var string = "!warn <@123456789123456789> I eat apples for breakfast";`
The `!warn` will always be at the start.
`<@` will always be at the start of the numbers.
`>` will always be at the end of the numbers.
The `<@****>` numbers are random and are never the same.
The length of the `<@****>` can range between 18-20 numbers.

I want to end up with the string `I eat apples for breakfast`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'd suggest using [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An alternative is using regex**

**Explanation:** https://regex101.com/r/SLhRMA/1

```js
var str = "!warn <@123456789123456789> I eat apples for breakfast";

console.log(str.replace(/!warn <@\d+>\s?/, ''))
```

Comment: My thought is `console.log(str.replace(/(?:\!warn \<@\d+\>)(.*?)/, '$1'))`

Comment: @Sphinx your approach is beautiful!

Comment: @Sphinx You'd probably want to trim that once making the replacement. Good approach though.

Comment: @SimonR, Yes, but that is not a big problem. I am thinking if the string is very large, which method will be more efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = "!warn <@123456789123456789> I eat apples for breakfast";

console.log(text.replace(/^\!warn <@.*?>\s?/,""));
```

How this works is it replaces the text based on the pattern provided (`/\!warn <@.*?>\s?/s`).

The first part is a literal check that it says !warn at the very beginning of the string (we escape the explanation point because that has a pattern meaning). Then we're checking for <@ and then any characters between the @ and >. We're using a non-greedy check - so it'll match up to the first >. Then we're checking for one single space so it makes the very first part of the bit you want as the first character.

An explaination of this is available on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rFGYOg/2)